# UIActionsheet Locks iphone screen

Tags: iphone

i am new to iphone...i have coded in viewdidload

```
-(void)viewDidload
{
     actSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"How"
                    delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"                         
                                       destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
}
```

when one button is pressed,
i coded like

```
[actSheet showInView:self.view];
```

but, the screen is full like locked,i could not do nothing....anyhelpplease?

Comment: The screen is locked, as in the UIActionSheet takes over and conceals your app (which is intended behavior), or locked, as in the sheet is displayed, but doesn't respond to user input? Also, the code you have there will display a sheet with no title, and no buttons... not a very useful thing to do!

Comment: i have inserted title,ok button also.......
if i use showInView:self.view in viewwillappear , it works fine.but
if i use IBAction button , it appears like that.....sir...

Answer (score 1):

At minimum you must implement the UIActionSheetDelegate method `– actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` in the object you have set as delegate (self). The sheet is automatically dismissed after the method is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

?